# Setting up a BroadcastReceiver in an Android AIR app

Tags: java, android, actionscript, air, air-native-extension

I am writing an app using Adobe AIR and attempting to deploy it to Android using native extensions. The app needs to be able to make use of Google's C2DM service (the equivalent of Apple's push notification service). This requires setting up a BroadcastReceiver in order to receive the registration of the device from Google. I am able to get this working fine in a standalone native Android app (no AIR), but cannot seem to get it to work in an AIR app. I am thinking I must be setting up the manifest XML wrong, but I can't see how.

Here is the relevant portion of the XML from the manifest file in the AIR app:

```
<android>
    <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
        <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
            <permission android:protectionLevel="signature" android:name="com.example.znotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

            <uses-permission android:name="com.example.znotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

            <application android:enabled="true">
                <receiver android:name="com.example.znotification.C2DMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">

                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                    </intent-filter>

                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                    </intent-filter>

                </receiver>
            </application>

        </manifest>

    ]]></manifestAdditions>
</android>
```

In the native Java class C2DMBroadcastReceiver which is referenced in the  tag, all it does is Log out a message saying it has received a broadcast. I've verified that I am setting up the Intent correctly (see Java code below), but the BroadcastReceiver never gets hit.

```
Context appContext = context.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
registrationIntent.putExtra("app",PendingIntent.getBroadcast(appContext, 0, new Intent(), 0));
registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", args[0].getAsString());
appContext.startService(registrationIntent);
```

Generally, how should a BroadcastReceiver be set up in the manifest XML for an AIR app? SPecifically, how in the XML do you tell the app to run the correct BroadcastReceiver upon receiving a given broadcast? Obviously, what I'm doing is incorrect...

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. I think you just have the android names for the AIR components slightly wrong. Try the below, noting the "air" prefix on a few of the classes.

```
<android>
<manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
    <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
        <permission android:protectionLevel="signature" android:name="air.com.example.znotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

        <uses-permission android:name="air.com.example.znotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

        <application android:enabled="true">
            <receiver android:name="com.example.znotification.C2DMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">

                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                    <category android:name="air.com.example.znotification" />
                </intent-filter>

                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                    <category android:name="air.com.example.znotification" />
                </intent-filter>

            </receiver>
        </application>

    </manifest>

]]></manifestAdditions>
```